# Using vb.net to add new column in excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I was hoping someone would be able to offer me some assistance please? My excel worksheet contains various columns, what I was hoping to do is simply just add another column at the end.  So if my worksheet contains 20 columns of data i wish to add header to column U1, next time if my worksheet had 22 columns of data I wish to add header to V1 and so on

Now I have managed to get the next column letter however when I try to pass text into the header row I get an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object on the following line

.Range(ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(lColumn + 1) & 1).Value = "TESTT"

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks

```
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim xWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lColumn As Long = 0

    xWorkbook = xls.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test.xlsx") 'File Location
    xWorksheet = xWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    xls.Visible = True

    With xWorksheet
        If xls.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns) <> 0 Then
            lColumn = .Columns.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            lColumn = 1
        End If
    End With

    With xWorksheet
              .Range(ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(lColumn + 1) & 1).Value = "TESTT"
    End With

Private Function ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(colIndex As Integer) As String
    Dim div As Integer = colIndex
    Dim colLetter As String = String.Empty
    Dim modnum As Integer = 0

    While div > 0
        modnum = (div - 1) Mod 26
        colLetter = Chr(65 + modnum) & colLetter
        div = CInt((div - modnum) \ 26)
    End While

    Return colLetter
End Function
```

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce, this code worked for me and added "Test" to "A2". Are you sure that part of the spreadsheet isn't locked or something, or a column isn't hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use option strict on you have to use cint for conversion, with this change your code works well

```
With xWorksheet
  .Range(ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(CInt(lColumn + 1)) & 1).Value = "TESTT"
End With
```